# silverlight database access problem

Tags: silverlight, deployment

For training purposes I created a simple silverlight 4 application which uses ADO.NET Entity Data Model and a Domain Service Class to connect to an SQL Express database to query it.

The database is fully accesible in the dev mode if I run the application from the Visual Studio 2010 but after deploying it on a server the database connections fail everytime with error message: Load operation failed for query ... Argumentst: NotFound.

Googling haven't gave me any help.
I suspect I am missing something in my IIS6 settings, but what?
My database has NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE setup for the database so I assumed the IIS requests should go through, but they don't.

Please help.
V

Comment: Have you checked your connection string. Even though my staging db and production db are on the same server, dev is on a different machine, the connection string is different for me when connecting from my staging machine rather than from production because of how I set it up when I initially accessed the server. I don't know if that is your problem but that is where I would start.

Comment: Hi Varuuknahl, The same connection string is the same for both dev and prod applications. Can you show me what difference you have between your dev and productional connectionstring?  Thanks. V

Comment: What do you think about my suspicion that it's problem of the sql express access via IIS? something with permissions to my DB...?? in the connection string i specify User ID=myUser;Password=pass;  but can this user get through IIS?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was very simple: always check the text of inner exeptions :-) for clues.  When you build a database accessing appl and run it from a dev machine, all of your services reference localhost, but when you deploy it should reference yourservername:port.  So, simply CTRL+H localhost:port to yourservername:port, then publish and enjoy the ride.  Cheers and thanks for help and clues.
Val